# Oddsratio package has uninstalled ggplot2 and I can't get it back

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried installing the oddsratio package and it first uninstalled my ggplot2 package and then failed to install itself. I can't re-install the ggplot package. Any thoughts?

Here's the error produced by the oddsratio package

> Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection ERROR: installing
>   vignettes failed
>   * removing '\ds.hund.ac.uk/staff/staff19/ABC/R/win-library/3.3/ggplot2' Warning
>   in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "\ds.hund.ac.uk\staff\staff19\ABC\R\win-library\3.3"
>   C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWewybe/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency 'ggplot2' is not
>   available for package 'cowplot'
>   * removing '\ds.hund.ac.uk/staff/staff19/ABC/R/win-library/3.3/cowplot' Warning
>   in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "\ds.hund.ac.uk\staff\staff19\ABC\R\win-library\3.3"
>   C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWewybe/downloaded_packages/cowplot_0.9.3.tar.gz'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘cowplot’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'ggplot2',
>   'cowplot' are not available for package 'oddsratio'
>   * removing '\ds.hund.ac.uk/staff/staff19/ABC/R/win-library/3.3/oddsratio'
>   Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "\ds.hund.ac.uk\staff\staff19\ABC\R\win-library\3.3"
>   C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWewybe/downloaded_packages/oddsratio_1.0.3.tar.gz'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘oddsratio’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWewybe\downloaded_packages’

**EDIT: SessionInfo() as requested**

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                            [5]
>   LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_3.3.2

Comment: Have you tried to install ggplot2 in a new session?

Comment: Yes, restarted a few times.

Comment: Can you provide your sessionInfo()?

Comment: @MLavoie I have added the sessionInfo. Nothing unusual seems to be there. When I try to install ggplot i get the same "non-zero exit warning". My hard drive isn't full either so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Your R version is almost 2 years old...

Comment: I'm using university computers which need admin to install stuff which is a pain. I've downloaded Anaconda with the latest packages so seems to be stable (I'm not going to try installing oddsratio though). Fingers crossed.